# How to calculate $ \lim_{x\to 0} (\frac{(5x + 1)^{20} - (20x + 1)^{5}}{\sqrt[5]{1 + 20x^{2}}-1}) $ without the rule of L'Hôpital?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} (\frac{(5x + 1)^{20} - (20x + 1)^{5}}{\sqrt[5]{1 + 20x^{2}}-1})
$$

Hello! I need to solve this limit. I had solved it with the rule of L'Hôpital, but i can't without it. I tried multiplicatio using Special Limits, but i simplified it only to $$ \lim_{x\to 0} (\frac{e^{100x} - e^{100x}}{e^{4x^2}-1})$$ So i think i had done something wrong and i should do it by another way. Please help me, I must solve it using only Special Limits and simple transformations. I can't use derivatives.

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to evaluate THAT?

Comment: You couldn't have simplified it to that because "that" is $0.$

Comment: For the numerator use binomial theorem to get $(190\cdot 25-10\cdot 400)x^2+o(x^2)$ and for denominator use the standard limit $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \dfrac{x^n-a^n} {x-a} =na^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the Taylor series on the bottom and expand the top, keeping only the first terms that do not cancel.
$$(5x + 1)^{20} - (20x + 1)^{5}=1+100x+20\cdot 19 \cdot \frac 12\cdot 5^2 x^2+O(x^3)-1-100x-5\cdot 4 \cdot \frac 12\cdot 20^2+O(x^3)\\=750x^2+O(x^3)\\
\sqrt[5]{1 + 20x^{2}}-1=1+\frac {20x^2}5+O(x^4)-1=4x^2+O(x^4)$$
and the ratio is just $$\frac {750}4+O(x)$$